# What is the name of the document form where the text (content) for a User Interface is defined?

Tags: documentation, language

Like: Do we call it File or Document. Especially important if you make an interface that will be adopted for several languages.

Comment: You'll have to be more clear, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "content" or for what sort of a user interface/application this is. Generally "File" has become much too broad so if you're talking about text I would say document.

Comment: Do you mean the copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called Copy. See ['Copy' on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_%28written%29):

> Copy refers to written material, in contrast to photographs or other elements of layout, in a large number of contexts, including magazines, advertising, and book publishing.
>   In advertising, web marketing and similar fields, copy refers to the output of copywriters, who are employed to write material which encourages consumers to buy goods or services.
>   In publishing more generally, the term copy refers to the text in books, magazines, and newspapers. In books, it means the text as written by the author, which the copy editor then prepares for typesetting and printing.
>   In newspapers and magazines, "body copy", the main article or text that writers are responsible for, is contrasted with "display copy," accompanying material such as headlines and captions, which are usually written by copy editors or sub-editors.

Comment: Perhaps there is no name for it. Now I'm working on a webapp which will be available in several languages. I put all the copy (text, button, description) in an excel document. That way I have all the texts gathered in one place. This makes it easier for me and for the translators. **Such kind of a document, does it have a special name: Yes or no?**

Answer (score 2):

Content Requirements Document i believe its called, if i understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of a "[Localization] Resource File"?
[See MSDN definition here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296240%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> Resource files are typically any non-executable data file used by your application, such as image, audio, and video files. A resource file can also have specific meanings in certain contexts. For example, in the context of application localization, resource files refer to .resx files, which you can deploy in localized satellite assemblies.

And technical details about how to do this in .NET [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5447/NET-Localization-using-Resource-file)

Comment: Thx. I was just searching for a general name for a document type that has all the copy of one application in it. For example you say "instruction manual" for a document with the instructions for a machine, electronic gadget, etc. So what would be a document where all that copy is inside.

But as it seems there is no general definiton, as those kind of information can be delivered in very different ways. Thanks for your input though :)